# In Python how to associate words to a list and then randomly print a value from the list?

Tags: python, list, random, input

**I want to find a way to call on a randomly selected value in a list by associating a word used by an input().**

*There are two "quote lists" (sadMessages and happyMessages) for now.*

So if I typed in "sad" the program will randomly pick from a "sad list"
And if I typed "happy" the program will randomly pick from a "happy list"
[image]
**This how it needs to look.**

```
import random

happy= ["It is during our darkest moments that we must focus to see the light.",
    "Tell me and I forget. Teach me and I remember. Involve me and I learn.",
    "Do not go where the path may lead, go instead where there is no path and leave a trail.",
    "You will face many defeats in life, but never let yourself be defeated.",
    "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",
    "In the end, it's not the years in your life that count. It's the life in your years.",
    "Never let the fear of striking out keep you from playing the game.",
    "Life is either a daring adventure or nothing at all."]

sad= ["Dont cry because it’s over, smile because it happened.",
    "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken",
    "No one can make you feel inferior without your consent.",
    "It’s not who you are that holds you back, its who you think you're not.",
    "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on."]

print("please choose between happy or sad")#I want to change this to (In one word type how you feel.)
answer = input ()
if answer == "happy":
    print("Check this out : " , random.choice(happy+sad))
elif answer == "sad":
    print("This might help out : " , random.choice(sad))
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite sure what you're asking? Also, try to keep your question and code as minimal as possible (ie. remove any non-relevant code)

Comment: please try to make the question more concise I am having trouble following. I think dictionary might be a better structure for your goal, but I am having trouble understanding your program.

Comment: I have made changes to question - Thank you.

Comment: You could store those two lists in a single dictionary with keys "sad" and "happy", and add new word lists to this dictionary. It would be easy enough to store these wordlists in a text file and load them into a dictionary at runtime. Beyond that, it isn't clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is helpful for you.

```py
import random
helper= {}
helper['happy']= ["It is during our darkest moments that we must focus to see the light.",
    "Tell me and I forget. Teach me and I remember. Involve me and I learn.",
    "Do not go where the path may lead, go instead where there is no path and leave a trail.",
    "You will face many defeats in life, but never let yourself be defeated.",
    "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",
    "In the end, it's not the years in your life that count. It's the life in your years.",
    "Never let the fear of striking out keep you from playing the game.",
    "Life is either a daring adventure or nothing at all."]

helper['sad']= ["Dont cry because it’s over, smile because it happened.",
    "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken",
    "No one can make you feel inferior without your consent.",
    "It’s not who you are that holds you back, its who you think you're not.",
    "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on."]

answer = input ('How do you feel : ')
print("Check this out : " , random.choice(helper[answer]))
```

Comment: Happy to help :)